# Custom LWC Component for Offline Support

Tags: lightning-web-components, chat

I am trying to implement a new embedded service deployment and I want the Offline Support just to be some text with a hyperlink to our contact us page.

I don't see an option to replace the offline support with a custom LWC component and just checking the community to see if anyone has done anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Have been wondering the same thing. By the looks of things in the **Embedded Service Deployment** settings we don't have any flexibility when it comes to the Offline support form.

Only allows custom Chat Header, Chat Messages, Minimized and Pre-Chat custom components.